# Load balancing application servers running in multiple docker containers

Tags: apache, docker, docker-compose, load-balancing

What i am doing : I am running jruby sinatra server in four different docker containers. And I did setup apache2 load balancer configuration in another docker container using ubuntu docker image.

Given below are the snapshots of docker containers, and httpd.conf configuration :

[image]

[image]

When i am hitting the url : 127.0.0.1:9292
It is showing home page of apache.
[image]

and on hitting url : 127.0.0.1:9292/load-manager . It's showing that requested url is not found.
[image]

Does anyone have any idea, what am i doing wrong or if i am missing something?

Comment: Since you used `ServerName myapachelb`, you have to add `127.0.0.1 myapachelb` to your `/etc/hosts` file, and then test using `http://myapachelb:9292`. Also, check if `mod_status` is loaded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution for this. 
I wasn't exposing the port which need to be accessed in other container(load balancer).

So, to communicate between the containers we need to expose ports. And Inside load balancer container we can either load balance nodes by their

IP_ADDRESS:PORT or CONTAINER_NAME:PORT

[image]